# Is there a more elegant way to do this in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, overriding, contravariance

It appears that C# 4.0 does not support covariance (using the "in" keyword) on parameters in overrides; is that the case?

If so, is there a more elegant way to do this?

**CONTEXT**

```
public interface IBaseEvent { /* ... */ }

public interface IDerivedEvent : IBaseEvent { /* ... */ }

public class MoreDerivedEvent : IDerivedEvent { /* ... */ }
```

I have a set of classes that handle `MoreDerivedEvent`.  Due to limitations of the event handling code, I can only register a single event handler for `MoreDerivedEvent`, and I don't know that it will handle registering interfaces as events (I don't believe it will, as the guidance is to use classes explicitly).  So, in order to handle the event appropriately, I've defined the handlers as follows:

```
public class BaseType
{
    protected virtual void Handle(IBaseEvent @event) { /* Do Base Stuff */ }
}

public class DerivedType
{
    protected virtual void Handle(IDerivedEvent @event)
    {
        /* Do Derived Stuff */
        Handle((IBaseEvent)@event);
    }

    protected override sealed void Handle(IBaseEvent @event)
    {
        base.Handle(@event);
    }
}
```

This obviously does not provide true inheritance, and I'll probably just flatten the types derived from `DerivedType` and `BaseType` if I can't solve this issue. But I figured I'd put it to the Stack Overflow community first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, parameter type covariance is *not typesafe*. Suppose we allowed parameter type covariance:

```
class B 
{
    public virtual void Frob(Animal a)
    {
    }
}
class D : B
{
    public override void Frob(Giraffe g)
    {
    }
}
....
B b = new D();
b.Frob(new Tiger());  // Calls D.Frob, which takes a giraffe.
```

No, *covariance* is not at all what you want. It is unsafe.  You want covariance on *return types*, not on *parameter types*. On parameter types you want *contravariance*:

```
class B 
{
    public virtual void Frob(Giraffe g)
    {
    }
}
class D : B
{
    public override void Frob(Animal a)
    {
    }
}
....
B b = new D();
b.Frob(new Giraffe());  // Calls D.Frob, which takes any animal.
```

No problem there.

Unfortunately for you, C# supports neither return type covariance nor parameter type contravariance. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the correction on co- versus contravariance; I've updated the question and tags.

Answer (score 2):

First you need an interface to specify the contra-variance on

```
public interface IBaseHandler<in T> where T : IBaseEvent
{
    void Handle(T handle);
}
```

Then you can define a base class to do 'base stuff'

```
public class BaseType<T> : IBaseHandler<T> where T : IBaseEvent
{
    public virtual void Handle(T handle) { /* do base stuff */} 
}
```

which will then allow you to override for the MoreDerivedEvent

```
public class MoreDerivedType : BaseType<MoreDerivedEvent>
{
    public override void Handle(MoreDerivedEvent handle)
    {
        base.Handle(handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - this is an interesting approach.  In this case, I don't prefer it because it introduces an interface that will not otherwise be used, and by definition causes my protected methods to become public.